# CodeLite color schemes (themes) messed up for C

Tags: c, color-scheme, codelite

I recently updated CodeLite for Linux (Debian) to version 14.0. I use CodeLite mostly for C and looks like the IDE messed up the color themes. Here I have [before (CodeLite 13.0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4SjJ.png) & [after (CodeLite 14.0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr5CX.png) **screenshots**.

Upon further "investigation" I found that it is not possible to set up a color theme exclusively for C (as it is for java, perl and basically any other language) but the C++ theme is the default for *.c files.

That prevents me form changing which keywords I want in which color because the IDE interprets almost all of C words (function signatures, fields, variables, constants, custom types...) as type 'identifier' and assigns the same color to all of them.

If I change the color of the word type 'identifier', [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyRnz.png). As you can see, it's almost as coding in a plain text editor (actually mousepad has more color diversity than CodeLite 14.0).

This happens with every theme I've tried and with some other languages too. I don't know if it's a bug or if there is **some way of bringing back the themes** to work in v14.0. I would also appreciate some advice at **installing the older CodeLite version 13.0** while this "bug" gets solved but this is a longer story so I've issued [another question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872389/installing-older-versions-of-codelite-v13-in-debian-5-8-14).