# Installing older versions of CodeLite (v13) in Debian 5.8.14

Tags: dependency-management, codelite

I had [some trouble with CodeLite v14.0 color schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833885/codelite-color-schemes-themes-messed-up-for-c) and wanted to go back to version 13, which worked fine before the update, at least while they fix that issue. I tried downloading the package from the [CodeLite release archive](https://downloads.codelite.org/ReleaseArchive.php) and install it:

```
$ gdebi CodeLite-13.0.8-gtk3-ubuntu-bionic-x86_64.deb 
[···]
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libhunspell-1.6-0
```

Looks like `libhunspell-1.6-0` is missing, but it's actually not! I just happen to have a **newer** version installed.

```
$ sudo apt install libhunspell-1.6-0
[···]
E: Unable to locate package libhunspell-1.6-0

$ sudo apt install libhunspell-1.7-0
[···]
libhunspell-1.7-0 is already the newest version (1.7.0-3).
```

How can this happen? How do I fix it? Should I consider downgrading to `libhunspell-1.6-0` (installing it from source, messing it up every time I `$ sudo apt upgrade` etc...)?